# Howto: osgi and shared packages?

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, osgi, karaf

Im trying to write an osgi-application that should make use of the  org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.
For this I have added the bundle servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch-client since it exports *org.elasticsearch.client* with the needed *RestHighLevelClient*. Apparently though, it seems that the *RestHighLevelClient* needs servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch (amongst others) to work so I add that aswell - both of the same version. Both of the bundles export *org.elasticsearch.client* but with different content.
Everything loads as expected and I can verify the exported packages.

**EDIT**:
The problem that im getting reviels it self as a ClassNotFound-exception for *org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient*. Which is odd since I can view that the elasticsearch-client is available and exporting the requred package.

My interpretation is that Karaf doesent seem to be able to handle shared packages. It seem to load one of the bundles that have the required package to suffice the requirement from my application-feature, and after that decides that it is enough even though the needed class actually exist in the the other bundle.

After comments from @ChristianSchneider and gaining some more understanding I have updated my configuration. However, the issue still remains.

I now have a elastisearch-client6-feature and an elasticsearch6-feature

```
   
    <feature name="elasticsearch6" version="6.3.2" description="Elasticsearch Base libraries">
        <bundle start-level="80">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch/6.3.2_1</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-cbor/2.9.6</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.6</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">wrap:mvn:com.vividsolutions/jts/1.13</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">wrap:mvn:io.sgr/s2-geometry-library-java/1.0.0</bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true"><![CDATA[wrap:mvn:io.netty/netty-all/4.1.28.Final$Bundle-Version=4.1.28&Export-Package=*;version=4.1.28]]></bundle>
        <bundle dependency="true">wrap:mvn:org.locationtech.jts/jts-core/1.15.1</bundle>
    </feature>

    <feature name="elasticsearch-client6" version="6.3.2" description="Elasticsearch Client libraries">
        <bundle start-level="80">mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch-client/6.3.2_1</bundle>
    </feature>
```

and my application-feature

```
    <feature name="my-application" version="${version}">
        <bundle start-level="92">mvn:com.mycompany/application-feature/${version}</bundle>
    </feature>
```

Can someone please suggest how I force my application-feature to both load the elasticsearch-client6-feature aswell as elasticesearch6 as they are both required.

Kind regards
Jiinx

Comment: Why do you wrap the bundles? The servicemix bundles should already provide the necessary OSGi metadata. What happens if you just load the bundles? If it is the same problem then I think this is an error in the servicemix bundles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ChristianSchneider. Ive updated the original question. Please if you have any more input it would be mych appreciated.

Comment: That looks better already. Now why do you wrap your bundle. In your build you should produce a valid bundle. The way you override Import-Package causes the import for org.elasticsearch.action to be missing. You should also remove dependency=true for your own bundle.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider I wrap it because I havent made my own source osgi-compliant just yet. The Import is because there is actually and older version of the elasticsearch-client around that, for a limited time atleast, have to coexist with my new bundle. How does dependency=true work? Should I realy need to specify that my source need elasticsearch when it is infact a transient dependency needed by elasticsearch-client? As indicated my-elastic-feature complains that it cant find ActionRequest from elasticsearch even though there is no reference to that in my source.

Comment: dependency=true means : Only install a bundle if another bundle needs it. This allows karaf to select the best bundle if there are several candidates. Your own bundle should normally not use this.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider Ive update some more after your suggestions but the original problem seem to remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and this is what I did...

1. Go to https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/all-versions which is a site that lets you download maven artifacts as well as all their dependencies, select the version you want.
2. After selecting the version click the red download button and it will download a zip file with all the elastic search jars and required dependencies.After downloading unzip the jar on your local file system.
3. Create a bundle like com.mycompany.thirdparty.elasticsearch
4. Create a lib folder in the root of the bundle and copy/paste all those jars you unzipped from the download into that folder.
5. Using eclipse MANIFEST editor go to Runtime Tab, in the class path section add all the jars in the lib folder. Then for exported packages click add and add all the packages available.

This creates a bundle that has elastic search and all its dependencies which are exported to other bundles that import elastic search packages or add the bundle as a dependency.

Hope that gets you in the right direction, its easiest to do this in eclipse with the MANIFEST editor because it automatically updates build.properties files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Duncan. I might have a go at that - Im running IntelliJ rather that eclipse but I excpect it be doable it that aswell or pref. directly in maven. Given the update of my problem - do you still see it as a solution?

Comment: I think the solution is honestly that jar-download.com site that lets you search for maven artifacts, just get ES client and its dependencies and figure out how to get it all into a bundle.

Comment: There is a mismatch between OSGI and maven and its kind of a pain, solutions like Tycho only partially address the issues sometimes its just easier to wrap jars in a bundle you need.