# Why org.apache.servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch-client does not find org.apache.http.client.AuthCache

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-camel, apache-karaf

### Problem

I'm trying to use the camel bundle **camel-elasticsearch-rest 2.22.2** in a **karaf 4.2.2** environment.

When I'm installing the camel bundle *camel-elasticsearch-rest* everything goes well and it install automatically its dependencies ([screenshot of camel-elasticsearch-rest install bundle in karaf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4AAV.png)):

- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch (*org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch/6.1.1_1*)
- org.apache.servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch-client (*org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch-client/6.1.1_1*)
- org.apache.httpcomponents.httpasyncclient (*org.apache.httpcomponents/httpasyncclient-osgi/4.1.3*)
- org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient (*org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.5.5*)
- org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore (*org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore-osgi/4.4.9*)

---

### Code

In my code I call the *camel-elasticsearch-rest* in this way:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class ServiceRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        CamelContext context = this.getContext();
        restConfiguration()
                .component("jetty")
                .host("localhost")
                .port(8200)
                .contextPath("/api")
                .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
                .apiProperty("cors", "true");

        rest("/elastic/test")
                .get("/")
                .route()
                .setBody(simple("{ \"indexName\": \"test-index\" }"))
                .to("elasticsearch-rest://elasticsearch?hostAddresses=127.0.0.1:9200&operation=INDEX&indexName=test-index&indexType=sample");
    }
}
```

I have installed my jar bundle on karaf, but when camel context starting I'm receiving this warning that cause the camel routes shutdown:

> 09:58:44.595 WARN [fileinstall-C:\Program
>   Files\apache-karaf\4.2.2/deploy] Listener caused an exception, will be
>   ignored java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/AuthCache
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.doInvokeAny(AbstractExecutorService.java:193)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.invokeAny(AbstractExecutorService.java:225)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper$4.call(ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.java:185)
>   ~[44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper$15.call(ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.java:446)
>   ~[44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.RWLock.runReadOperation(RWLock.java:33)
>   ~[44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.runUnlessShutdown(ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.java:443)
>   ~[44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.invokeAny(ScheduledExecutorServiceWrapper.java:180)
>   ~[44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher.callListener(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:188)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher.callListeners(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:178)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher.blueprintEvent(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:133)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:427)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:278)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:299)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:268)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:264)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:254)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)
>   [44:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.10.1]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1179)
>   [?:?]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:730)
>   [?:?]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:485)
>   [?:?]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4579)
>   [?:?]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2174) [?:?]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998) [?:?]
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1260)
>   [10:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.6.4]
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1233)
>   [10:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.6.4]
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:520)
>   [10:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.6.4]
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:365)
>   [10:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.6.4]
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:316)
>   [10:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.6.4] Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/AuthCache
>           at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer.createClient(ElasticsearchProducer.java:255)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer.startClient(ElasticsearchProducer.java:246)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer.doStart(ElasticsearchProducer.java:237)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DeferServiceStartupListener.onCamelContextStarted(DeferServiceStartupListener.java:49)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3863)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3642)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3494)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:209)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3253)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3249)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3272)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3249)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3165)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.start(BlueprintCamelContext.java:243)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.maybeStart(BlueprintCamelContext.java:283)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.blueprintEvent(BlueprintCamelContext.java:177)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher$3.call(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:190)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher$3.call(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:188)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:?] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.AuthCache not
>   found by org.apache.servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch-client [124]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1639)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer.createClient(ElasticsearchProducer.java:255)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer.startClient(ElasticsearchProducer.java:246)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.component.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProducer.doStart(ElasticsearchProducer.java:237)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DeferServiceStartupListener.onCamelContextStarted(DeferServiceStartupListener.java:49)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3863)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3642)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3494)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:209)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3253)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3249)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3272)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3249)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3165)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.start(BlueprintCamelContext.java:243)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.maybeStart(BlueprintCamelContext.java:283)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.blueprintEvent(BlueprintCamelContext.java:177)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher$3.call(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:190)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintEventDispatcher$3.call(BlueprintEventDispatcher.java:188)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[?:?]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:?]

---

### Question

My question is why *org.apache.servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch-client* does not find the class *org.apache.http.client.AuthCache*.

This class should be in the dependency *org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient* that is correctly installed on karaf.

I have seen that in *the org.apache.servicemix.bundles.elasticsearch-client* bundle there aren't imported packages ([screenshot of the imported packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4AAV.png)), it is normal? It's a bug or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

elasticsearch-client is not supported in KARAF(OSGi)

ref:https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.23.x/platforms/karaf/features/src/main/resources/features.xml#L617

discussion on elasticsearch-client OSGi support:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28707

However you can build this as OSGi bundle as explained here:[Howto: osgi and shared packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790693/howto-osgi-and-shared-packages)